# Spring MVC and BlueMix

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ibm-cloud

Hello I'm trying to deploy a RESTful Web Service with Spring MVC on BlueMix. 
For testing I'm trying to deploy this demo app into an app that I can deploy on BlueMix: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I'm struggling on this task and wonder if this is an easy thing to do? I hope this question is not too broad - but what do I need to change in order to get this running?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, test your application in your development environment (e.g. eclipse with local app server) and make sure app works for unit test cases.

You can refer to http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html for usage details.

Post that generate a WAR file and then try deploying on bluemix.
if you are using db service as well for development, you need to create appropriate properties file to hold the db service information. If you are a CF application, you can dynamically handle VCAP_SERVICES inside your java application. Refer to following forum for details.
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/9802/use-vcap_services-at-app-runtime-is-possible/

Answer (score 0):

To deploy your demo you have to use cf command line tool. It's used to log in to Bluemix. You can use different commands but you need only these:

```
cf api https://api.mybluemix.net
cf login
cf push
```

You can access your app overview page in the Bluemix Dashboard, there you can download the starter application package. It's very useful because you can find the initial configuration that your need for your apps.

In this article you can find how to download the starter application package:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-hangman-app/index.html

This article use java but all the bluemix deploys are similar.